# Debugging VS2008 VBScript custom install task

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vbscript, installation, windows-installer, custom-action

I have an install project which has a custom action that executes a VBScript file.  As it stands, this installation fails during the execution of this script with the following error:

```
There is a problem with this Windows Installer package.  A script required for this install to complete could not be run.  Contact your support personnel or package vender.
```

The script looks fine to me, but I can't see a way to debug it.  Is there a way to output a trace message, or even pause execution of an install script for this purpose?

Comment: You can also try to execute the script directly, not from MSI, I mean using `cscript` or `wscript`. However, you may need to adjust it.

Comment: For reference, read why [VBScript MSI CustomActions suck](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/robmen_20040520.htm) - it's much more robust to use C++. Even if it can't be done for this release (generally the case when Setup devs are under pressure to release), it's something to consider for the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to insert the following lines into your script to output debug messages to a log file:

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = objFso.OpenTextFile("C:\Temp\logfile.txt", 8, True)
f.WriteLine "Debug message text"
f.Close
```